Undesirable Indentation of Curly-Brace Initializer Inside Argument List
Using C++ mode, I don't want the following indentation when using curly-brace initializers inside argument lists.
variable = calc({
    { "key1", 12 },
    { "key2", 24 }
  });

I want this one:
variable = calc({
  { "key1", 12 },
  { "key2", 24 }
});

ChatGPT couldn't solve it, so I guess I'm back to using Stack Exchange again.

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info
